# Is there a difference between SYN-ACK and SEQ-ACK?

Tags: tcp

I've been trying to understand if there's a difference between the two, if any. Wireshark mentions SEQ-ACK under their TCP information of a packet, but I've typically heard this referred to as SYN-ACK. Is there a difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SYN-ACK is part of the triple SYN+SYN-ACK+ACK handshake to initialize a TCP socket and SYNchronize its sequence numbers.

SEQ-ACK is a running ACKnowledgement during a TCP transfer, usually advancing the SEQuence number(s).